# Bash in php exec in webpage don't colors for png and mp3 files on Linux

Tags: colors, php, exec, ansi-term

I have code like this in php:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
exec("/bin/bash -c 'ls --color=always'", $result);
echo implode("\n", $result);
```

and I've got result (escape is not visible)

```
Makefile
README
Yann Tiersen - Comptine d'un autre ete L'apres midi.mp3
bush-src.js
bush.js
bush.min.js
[0m[01;34mcgi-bin[0m
config.json
[01;34mcss[0m
favicon.ico
foo.png
index.php
[01;34mlib[0m
ls.txt
test.php
test.php~
[01;32mtest.txt[0m
```

It show ANSI escape codes for directories and executable files, but when I call from command line

```
php -r "exec('bash -c \"ls --color=always\"', \$result);echo implode(\"\\n\", \$result);" | less
```

I've got this:

```
bush.js
bush.min.js
bush-src.js
ESC[0mESC[01;34mcgi-binESC[0m
config.json
ESC[01;34mcssESC[0m
favicon.ico
ESC[01;35mfoo.pngESC[0m
index.php
ESC[01;34mlibESC[0m
ls.txt
Makefile
README
test.php
test.php~
ESC[01;32mtest.txtESC[0m
ESC[00;36mYann Tiersen - Comptine d'un autre ete L'apres midi.mp3ESC[0m
```

png and mp3 have ANSI escapes codes, why php exec from webpage don't give that as return?

Comment: You probably have a `$LS_COLORS` variable defined somewhere in your `~/.bashrc`/`~/.zshrc`... (probably via a call of `eval "$(dircolors)"`)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas You're right, I have that `if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    eval "`dircolors -b`"
fi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a `$LS_COLORS` environment variable defined somewhere in your `~/.bashrc`/`~/.zshrc`... (probably via a call of `eval "$(dircolors)"`).

The `php` that you run on the command-line will inherit your shell's environment, including that `$LS_COLORS` variable.

While the one started by `apache2` will inherit `apache2`'s environment which is unlikely to have `$LS_COLORS` in it. `bash` doesn't read `~/.bashrc` (and anyway that would be the `~/.bashrc` of the user running apache if it did) when not run interactively (except in corner cases like when invoked by `sshd`/`rshd`/`telnetd`).

Note that `php`'s `exec()` already starts a shell, so you don't need to start another one (especially `bash` which is the slowest shell in the west).

```
 exec('ls --color=always', $result);
```

should be enough.

```
$ strace -fe execve php -r 'exec("bash -c echo\ test");'
execve("/usr/bin/php", ["php", "-r", "exec(\"bash -c echo\\ test\");"], [/* 49 vars */]) = 0
[pid  3608] execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "bash -c echo\\ test"], [/* 49 vars */]) = 0
[pid  3608] execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "echo test"], [/* 48 vars */]) = 0
```

Comment: exec call sh not bash.

Comment: I've ask another question about dircolors http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115899/why-dircolors-dont-return-enything-for-bash-called-from-php

Answer (score 0):

that's because it's not sending html but text

Comment: Don't undertand, this is test code that send ANSI escape but they are not send for mp3 and png files.

Comment: check the html in output and post that result here

Comment: I have text/plain as output I put just that. It's not html related at all.

Comment: and how would you expect this to be  colored if you are using a browser?

Comment: I ask about ANSI escape sequences that are not send to browser. I've replaced color with ANSI escape in question.

Comment: ah! now i understand what you mean, let me do some tests

Comment: have you tried running the php code with the same user of the webserver (usually www-data)?

Answer (score 0):

In my .bashrc file there is:

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    eval "`dircolors -b`"
fi
```

which color the files.