# Why dircolors don't return enything for bash called from php

Tags: bash, colors, php, ansi-term

I have this code in php:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
exec("/bin/bash -c 'dircolors -b'", $result);
echo implode("\n", $result);
```

but it return

```
LS_COLORS='';
export LS_COLORS
```

Why I'm not getting color ANSI codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when I put `export TERM="xterm"` before `dircolors`.

Comment: Yes, see the output of `dircolors -p` for the list of terminals for which `dircolors` would set the colors and how.